# MassTransit for Azure Service Bus receive messages in batch to avoid throttling

Tags: .net, azureservicebus, masstransit

Is there a way in MassTransit that we can receive multiple messages in single call?
I am using `MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core 6.0.2` in a Windows service.

Azure service bus has a throttle of 1000 credit limits per sec:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-throttling

Our scenario is a single topic with 200 subscriptions. Because of that limit, the throughput is only 2 message per second which is pretty low. Any extra call is throttled by Azure.

It would be great if MassTransit can retrieve 100 messages in 1 call to avoid throttling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit does not *receive* message by making calls to Azure, consumers are configured using AMQP and are pushed from the broker. This is the default behavior out of the box. If you are changing the protocol to something else, such as WebSockets, that may change how messages are delivered under the hood but I don't know how that affects service metering in Azure Service Bus.

Nothing MassTransit could do at this point would change how message credits are used. You might look at how Azure manages pricing with a 200 subscription topic (that seems excessive to me).